# Binary-operator to Multi-operator Decorator

Tags: python, decorator

Suppose I have a function which I have written as a binary-operator (binop), how do I extend it to a multi-operator (multiop) which takes an arbitrary number of arguments? Is there such a decorator in a library (e.g. in [functools](http://docs.python.org/library/functools.html))?

For example (I want a decorator to give this behaviour):

```
@binop_to_multiop
def mult(a,b):
    return a*b

mult(2,3,4) # 2*3*4 = 24
mult(7) # 7
mult(2,3) # 6
```

*Obviously I can't ask a question about decorators without mentioning, this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1594484/1240268).*

.

I've tried writing my own, but can't *quite* get it working, any explanation of where I'm going wrong would also be welcome:

```
def binop_to_multiop(f):
    @functools.wraps(f)
    def wrapper(*args, **kwds):
        if len(args) == 1: return args[0] # fails
        return f(args[0],(f(*args[1:], **kwds)), **kwds) #recursion attempt fails
    return wrapper
```

*Gives a* `TypeError: mult() takes exactly 2 arguments (N given)` *(for various `N!=2`).*

Comment: Your recursion should call `wrapper(*args[1:], **kwds)`, not `f(...)`.

Comment: One thing: You're creating a multi-parameter _function_, not _operator_. In Python, an operator is a special kind of function called when special syntax is encountered (e.g., `2 * 3`). There's really no way to make a multi-operand version of an operator, but then you usually don't have to, because the obvious syntax (e.g., `2 * 3 * 4 * 5`) already just works.

Comment: @abarnert Good nit-pick! :). I was thinking lisp style `(* 2 3 4)` which might make more sense (although [all operators are just functions in lisp](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operator_(programming)#cite_note-LispOperators-0)).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your attempt to code it yourself was very close to working. You just need to change the recursive step to recurse on `wrapper` rather passing all but one argument to `f`:

```
def binop_to_multiop(f):
    @functools.wraps(f)
    def wrapper(*args, **kwds):
        if len(args) == 1: return args[0]
        return f(args[0], wrapper(*args[1:], **kwds), **kwds)
    return wrapper
```

I didn't have any problems with the base case, so I'm not sure what your comment `#fails` was about.

You may also need to think about which end of the list you start solving from (that is, does your operator have [left or right associativity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operator_associativity)). For operators like multiplication and addition it won't matter since `(a+b)+c = a+(b+c)`, but for other you may get strange results. For instance, subtraction may not work as you might expect:

```
@binop_to_multiop
def sub(a, b):
    return a - b
```

With the decorator defined above, `sub(a, b, c)` will give a different result than `a-b-c` (it will do `a-(b-c)` instead of `(a-b)-c`). If you want them to behave the same way, you can redefine the decorator to be left associative (like most mathematical operators do in most computer languages) like this:

```
def left_associative_binop_to_multiop(f):
    @functools.wraps(f)
    def wrapper(*args, **kwds):
        if len(args) == 1: return args[0]
        return f(wrapper(*args[:-1], **kwds), args[-1], **kwds)
    return wrapper
```

A more sophisticated approach would be to make the associativity be a parameter to the decorator, but that gets tricky if you don't want the parameter to be required.

Comment: That's the insight I was missing! Thanks. (I thought it "fails" as `mult(4)` gave an error.)

Comment: +1. The reduce implementation is probably better, but this implementation is probably easier to understand for the OP, because it's just a fixed version of what he already tried.

Answer (score 4):

`reduce()` comes to mind:

```
from functools import wraps

def binop_to_multiop(binop):
    @wraps(binop)
    def multiop(x, *xs):
        return reduce(binop, xs, x)
    return multiop

# ...

@binop_to_multiop
def mult(a, b):
    return a * b

print mult(2, 3, 4)
print mult(7)
print mult(2, 3)
```

Result:

```
$ python multiop.py
24
7
6
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I'm a fan of reduce! Does this deal with `**kwds`?

Comment: @hayden: No, it does not, but I don't quite see the point, since a binary operator that takes two arguments plus an unspecified number of additional keyword arguments ceases to be a binary operator, does it not?

Comment: +1 for using `wraps`, unlike the otherwise-equivalent answer (yours was also earlier, and has slightly better names).

Comment: hmm, actually mine was earlier before I edited it with "if args else None' part.

Answer (score 3):

```
def binop_to_multiop(f):
    def wrapper(*args):
        return reduce(f, args) if args else None
    return wrapper

@binop_to_multiop
def mult(a, b):
    return a*b

print mult(2,3,4)
print mult(7)
print mult(2,3)
print mult(4,5,6,7)
```

gives
24
7
6
840